Get hover effect when hovering on text that is over the image
I am trying to get a hover effect when trying to hover over a text that is on top of my image.
You can see in this codesandbox that I am trying to scale my image when the cursor is hovering over it, however, I noticed the hover effect does not take place when the cursor is moving over the text. I guess that makes sense, since the text component is over the image.
One thing that I was exploring was using pointer-events:none, however, I can see that I lose the capability of copying the text from the image.
My question is, is it possible to get the transition effect on the image when the cursor moves around the text? Maybe there is something obvious that I am missing.
Note: I don't want the text to scale, just the image.
Thanks in advance.

Post your [mcve] here please, not on another site

If you apply the hover to the container it works for both elements.
In the example you provided just change
img:hover {
    transform: scale(1.05);
}

to
.wrapper:hover img {
    transform: scale(1.05);
}

and hover effect will be working while hovering the text
